# Layout management in Qt

Tags: qt, qlayout, qgroupbox

I have a small program which contains a `QGroupBox` with other widgets like this: 
[image]

I tried many ways to manage the size of the `QGroupBox` to make the height as the same as the rest of the parts. Except for the way of using `setMaximumHeight`, because I want the size to change dynamically with the window size too. what else can I do to manage the layout?

Comment: Try to add a stretch to your vertical layout  with `QBoxLayout::addStretch()`.

Comment: Put a spacer to the end of that layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there are three items in a layout. The layout will try to fill the available space. `QLineEdit` and `QSpinBox` (or whatever your second widget is) have SizePolicy.vertical == fixed, so all extra space goes to the `QGroupBox`.

You have these choices:

- Add a vertical spacer as fourth item below the groupbox to your layout.
- Set maximum height of your groupbox - then the remaining space will be evenly spaced between the items.
- Adjust the size of your window / widget / dialog (in Qt Designer or via code).